# Using Translate pipe in Ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

Does anyone have a working example of the Translate pipe for Ionic 2?

```
console.log("trans: "+this.trans.translate('Location')); // works fine in code
```

According to http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/utils/translation/ the template syntax should be:

```
<h2>{{'My example key' | translate}}</h2>
```

For me this results in the following JS error:

```
EXCEPTION: Cannot find pipe 'translate'. in [null]BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ app.bundle.js:36432
```

Comment: Did you import the pipe in your component ? And set it in the pipe array of the ***@Component*** decorator ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import and insert TranslatePipe in your @Page like so:

```
import {Page, TranslatePipe} from 'ionic/ionic';

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html',
  pipes: [TranslatePipe]
})
```

See: http://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-use-pipes-to-manipulate-data-in-ionic-2/

Comment: The Page, or should I say Component decorator doesn't take pipes as an argument anymore. Any ideas where to do this? The official Ionic 2 docs don't have anything on this...

Comment: That changed with Ionic 2 RC 0. Import them in the `app.module.ts` and add them to `declarations: []` and completely remove it from the other components.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out after googling for a while. My setup is a bit different in that I have a `page.module.ts` and a `component.module.ts` as well to break everything down into their own `@NgModule`. I had to declare it in my `component.module.ts`, then `export` it as well as `declaration` it. Should update your accepted answer for the future.